# What ip should I connect socket to when communicating between two machines(ZeroMQ)

Tags: c++, networking, ip-address, zeromq

What IP adress should be used to connect to server running on my pc from other machines? In my server, I call zmq_bind to listen for all incoming connections, like this:

```
zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://*:12781");
```

In my client, I try to connect to the server by:

```
string IP = "127.0.0.1";    //what should be here?
string connection_string = "tcp://" + IP + ":12781";
zmq_connect(socket, connection_string);
```

My program works already when the server and client are running on the same computer(IP is 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' or '192.168.1.13'). What IP should I use when connecting from other computers? I already tried my IPV4 which I found [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/), it didn't work.
Thanks for help.

Comment: This depends on your networking setup. For example if your *external IP* (the one you linked to) is behind a router you may need to configure your router to open that port and redirect traffic to your *internal IP*. Can you describe your exact setup in more detail?

Comment: "What IP adress should be used to connect to server" - well, the *actual IP of the server*, obviously. Every machine has a unique IP on your network (unless it was set up by morons) and the unique IP of the server is what you should use. However, if whomever set up the network was a *little bit* more clever, then they would have ensured that the machines did not just have IP addresses, but DNS names, so that instead of a numerical address you could use something more human readable like "server.my-lan.local" (or whatever).

Comment: How can I configure my router to do this? My router is from Netgear and I am using windows 10.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How can I get the actual IP of the server?

Comment: 1) log onto the machine and look up its networking configuration. 2) know its DNS name and query your local DNS server (assuming there is one).

Comment: Thanks for answers everyone. I managed to solve my problem using port forwarding on my router (mainly thanks to @Galik 's answer). I am grateful for your help. Goodbye.